# show image if adblock blocks adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads, adblock

I am trying to show a div if visitors are using adblock.

I was originally using a background-image, but most users actually see that message even if they aren't blocking ads, for a second or two, before the ad initializes.

I've searched the web and this site and it seems javascript is the best solutions. The only issue I am having is that it seems every answer here is missing a bit of key info, for nubs like myself.

So I am curious, how would I show a div in place of an adsense ad, specifically?

What I have been trying so far, which has had a bit of success is seeing if the ad container has no height and then displaying a popup (got the code from a tutorial online). But I don't want a popup just to display a div in the same spot as the ad.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TestPage() {
        if ($('.ad').height() == 0)
             $('.adblocked').show();

    }

    $(TestPage);
</script>
```

The above doesn't work to show the div, but it does detect when the ad are blocked, just having trouble showing that div `.adblocked` in it's place.

Comment: look into this http://idahospuds.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/how-to-detect-block-ads-using-google.html

Comment: Thanks, had a read through, I am very new to this so I was hoping for a hand holding tutorial with little expectations as far as js knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Adblock can take a few seconds to hide elements so set a timeout, something like this. You can increase the delay but 3000 usually does the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function TestPage() {
 if (jQuery('.ad').height() == 0) {
  document.getElementById("test").className += " adblocked";
 }
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 window.setTimeout('TestPage()', 3000); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TestPage() {
        if (jQuery('.ad').height() == 0)
             document.getElementById("test").className += " adblocked";

    }

    jQuery(TestPage);
</script>
```

Got it to work; some parts of several tutorials helped me get there.

If anyone else is trying to do this here is what I did:

Several replies here and tutorials online suggested trying to find out if the ad was 'blocked' or not loaded by getting the adlibraryname or something equivalent. I had no idea how to find that, so I did it with the height.

I put a div around the advert called `.ad` and in the jquery function above it looks to see if the height of the `div` is 0 (ad not loaded). in the same main ad box (`.ad` is wrapped in a parent div, lets call it `#wrap`) I put another `div` called `#test`.

In my style sheet I made another `div` called `.adblocked` that has a `background-image` with a nice message for people adblocking.

So essentially when an ad is blocked, it fills `#test` with `.adblocked`.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZdzX/ (change the height of `.ad` to see)

Now my only concern is whether or not this will call the `.adblocked` if the actual ad isn't blocked but just taking long to load...